# Passing a shell variable to awk in gnuplot

Tags: variables, awk, gnuplot

I need to pass a shell variable to awk in gnuplot but I get error messages :
The variable is set in the sript and is called FILE. This changes according to date.
My code : (in a Gnuplot script)

```
plot FILE using 1:14 with points pointtype 7 pointsize 1 # this works fine

replot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $14; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 100) printf("\n") ; if (NR > 1 && y2 -y1 <= -100) printf("\n"); print}'' FILE' using 1:14 with linespoints 
Err msg
awk: fatal: cannot open file `FILE' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

When I hard code the FILE path the replot works.

Could anyone clarify the code I need to pass this variable to awk? Am I on the right track with something like :

```
% environment_variable=FILE
% awk -vawk_variable="${environment_variable}" 'BEGIN { print awk_variable }' ?
```

Here is my Gnuplot script code: cobbled together from other posts mostly..

```
#FILE selection - we want to plot the most recent data file

FILE = strftime('/data/%Y-%m-%d.txt', time(0))  # this is correct

print "FILE is : " .FILE

#set file path variable for awk :      (This is where my problem is)

awk -v var="$FILE" '{print var}'

awk '{print $0}' <<< "$FILE"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your first script, use `"$FILE"` instead of `FILE`. in your second, on the last line you don't need `<<<`. `awk -v var="$FILE" '{print var}'` is incomplete syntax and will hang your computer as it needs a file as argument. Just use `awk '{print $0}' "$FILE"`

Comment: @Ploutox He need the `<<<`, its get the data from a variable into `awk` with this.

Comment: @Jotne oh, I thought `FILE` just stored the path of the file, not its entire content. If that's the case then you are right indeed. EDIT: after further reading, it seems OP just stored the path of the most recent file in `$FILE`. He should then remove the `<<<` (otherwise his awk command will just print the path)

Comment: @Ploutox - you are correct - just the file path is stored in $FILE ; not the actual contents - these are parsed by Gnuplot

Comment: when I use : awk '{print $0}' "$FILE" (in my gnuplot script) I get an err msg : invalid command

Answer (score 2):

If `FILE` is a gnuplot variable that contains the path of the file, you can do this:

```
FILE = 'input'
plot '<awk ''1'' ' . FILE
```

This concatenates the value of the gnuplot variable `FILE` onto the end of the awk command. The resulting awk "script" is therefore `awk '1' input` (which just prints every line of the file); you can substitute the `'1'` for whatever it is you want to do with awk.

By the way, your awk script can be simplified a little bit to this:

```
awk '{ y1 = y2; y2 = $14 } NR > 1 && (y2 - y1 >= 100 || y2 - y1 <= -100) { print "" } { print $1, $14 }'
```

It's not often that you need to use `if` in awk, as each block `{ }` is executed conditionally (or if no condition is specified, the block is always executed). Assuming you haven't modified the record separator (the `RS` variable), `print ""` is the same as `printf("\n")`. Rather than specifying `using 1:14` in gnuplot, you may as well only print the columns that you are interested in using `print $1, $14`.

So your `replot` line in gnuplot would be:

```
replot '<awk ''{ y1 = y2; y2 = $14 } NR > 1 && (y2 - y1 >= 100 || y2 - y1 <= -100) { print "" } { print $1, $14 }'' ' . FILE with linespoints
```

Of course, this line is getting a bit long. You might want to split it up a bit:

```
awk_cmd = '{ y1 = y2; y2 = $14 } NR > 1 && (y2 - y1 >= 100 || y2 - y1 <= -100) { print "" } { print $1, $14 }'
replot sprintf("<awk '%s' %s", awk_cmd, FILE) with linespoints
```

Comment: Still struggling with this. I set FILE = strftime('/data/%Y-%m-%d.txt', time(0)) (in my gnuplot script)...To get this variable FILE into awk I am trying this : `awk -v 'var=FILE '{print var}'' .....is my syntax correct? AWk stubbornly refuses to read the variable and use it...Any help again much appreciated..

Comment: Do you want awk to process the file whose name is stored in the gnuplot variable `FILE`? If so, my answer tells you how to do that. If not, what exactly are you trying to do? Why would you want an awk script to print the value of a gnuplot variable? Please update your question to clarify. By the way, you still haven't accepted my answer to your previous question. I would appreciate it if you did.

Comment: Hi Tom - yes your initial answer seems correct - but I cannot get the code to work in my script. I am using awk because I need to do conditional plotting ie some data points must join and others do not based on their value. Here is the code + err msg: gnuplot> plot '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $12; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 100) printf("\n") ; if (NR > 1 && y2 -y1 <= -100) printf("\n"); print}'. FILE using 1:12 with linespoints sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file  warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

Comment: You haven't ended the awk command with `''`. change `print}'. FILE` to `print}'' '. FILE`. Or better yet, use the code in my answer but change the `$14`s to `$12`s.